# Post Fetch api recarga la pagina con button de type="button"

Tags: javascript, post, botón, fetch

Tengo un problema con fetch cuando realizo el metodo POST con mi funcion postFetch() hacia una base de datos local con json-server. La solicitud llega vacia al servidor(es decir solo aparece el id) y la pagina si o si se recarga. Mi idea es que el POST se haga y luego aparezca en la pagina pero sin actualizarse esta asi que uso botones de tipo button y no submit. Pero no puedo hacer que pagina no se recargue. Tampoco me tira error.

```
<div id="contenedor"></div>>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>
                    Peliculas
                </legend>
                <label for="input-nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" id="input-nombre" name="input-nombre">
                <label for="input-director">Director</label>
                <input type="text" id="input-director" name="input-director">
                <label for="input-clasificacion">Clasificacion</label>
                <input type="text" id="input-clasificacion" name="input-director">

                <button id="btnEnviar" type="button">Enviar</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

Aqui en el codigo intente poner el e.preventDefault antes de la funcion postFetch() y no pasa nada.
Por lo que estoy viendo el problema es solo con el Post poque probe realizar un Get y que salgalo actualizado en un div, todo sin recargar la pag, y se me funciona.

```
const $btnEnviar = document.getElementById('btnEnviar'),
        $div = document.getElementById('contenedor');

let nombre = document.getElementById('input-nombre').value,
        director = document.getElementById('input-director').value,
        clasificacion = document.getElementById('input-clasificacion').value;

    const update = {
            nombre,
            director,
            clasificacion,
        };
    
    $div.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log(update)
        e.preventDefault();
        postFetch()
        
    });

    //Metodo Post con Fetch
    const postFetch = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/peliculas', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'aplication/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(update),
        })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.ok) {
                    return res.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error(`${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
                }
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
            });
    };
```

PD: Probe hacer un Post con el Insomnia y se hizo correctamente.

PD2: En la consola antes de que se recargue me sale el console.log(res) del segundo then pero me devuelve un objeto con un id dentro.

Comment: ¿A qué elemento hace referencia la variable `$div` y dónde defines la variable `update`? ¿Aparece algún mensaje en la consola? Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/549869/edit) para agregar el código HTML y Javascript que falta, de otra forma, va a ser muy difícil ayudarte.

Comment: No me permitia poner tanto codigo asi que recorte un poco, pero claramente me faltaron cosas asi que pido disculpas. Creo que ahi quedo entendible.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores:

- Un DIV no tiene método `submit` y nunca se va a disparar el evento asignado. En todo caso, si tienes un formulario, ese es el que debes usar para escuchar el evento
- Un botón con `type="button"` no hace que se envíe el formulario, ese comportamiento aplica solo a los que tienen `type="submit"`, por lo que la recarga de la página no es "culpa" del DIV ni del botón, si sigue pasando, hay que ver qué otro elemento es el que provoca el envío del formulario
- Estás tomando los valores de los campos desde que se carga la página, es decir, en blanco y no se actualizan cuando el usuario los modifica. Debes esperar a que se haga clic en el botón para tomarlos y crear el objeto `update`
- En el objeto `update` solo estás poniendo valores, pero no las propiedades (nombre de variable)
- Creas un encabezado para identificar el contenido como JSON, entonces, debes enviar un objeto y no su representación como cadena

Revisa los comentarios en el código, que complementan los puntos anteriores.

```js
// Solo necesitas el botón
const btnEnviar = document.querySelector('#btnEnviar');

// Obtener campos como elemento, no solo el valor
let nombre = document.getElementById('input-nombre'),
    director = document.getElementById('input-director'),
    clasificacion = document.getElementById('input-clasificacion');

// Todavía no se deben obtener los valores
// El objeto update debe contener valores actualizados

$btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    postFetch();
});

//Metodo Post con Fetch
const postFetch = () => {
    // Aquí obtienes los valores y creas el objeto con variable: valor
    const update = {
        nombre: nombre.value,
        director: director.value,
        clasificacion: clasificacion.value
    };
    // Ahora sí puedes ver el objeto
    console.log(update);
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/peliculas', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'aplication/json',
        },
        // Envía el objeto de acuerdo al encabezado, no es necesario JSON.stringify()
        body: update,
    })
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
    });
};
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Peliculas</legend>
        <label for="input-nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="input-nombre" name="input-nombre">
        <label for="input-director">Director</label>
        <input type="text" id="input-director" name="input-director">
        <label for="input-clasificacion">Clasificacion</label>
        <input type="text" id="input-clasificacion" name="input-director">

        <button id="btnEnviar" type="button">Enviar</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Nota final: No es necesario anteponer `$` a los nombres de variable en Javascript, aunque tampoco es un error, pero puede resultar en confusiones, sobre todo si usas PHP en el servidor.